# Moving NFS MW TO SD CARD

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd

I am using Asus zenfone 5 running 4.4 kitkat, i have moved many games with obb files to sd card but when i was trying to move nfs most wanted to sd card but i noticed that it doesn't have an obb file rather it has multiple game files in android data folder, when i moved it to sd card via settings the data wasn't moved it is still occupying 1.95 gb on my internal storage, please help me move the game, and yes, my phone is under warranty so i don't want to root it